# List<dynamic> to ComboBox

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, dapper

This code get a `list<dynamic>` from a repository class using `Dapper`. I need to bind this list to a `ComboBox`. The only way I can get this to work is by using a simple class (`ComboBoxItem` in my case) and than use that to do the binding.

UI.cs

```
var mRep= new MaterialRepository();

comboBox1.Items.Clear();
foreach (var item in listMaterial)
{
  comboBox1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem(Convert.ToString(item.code),Convert.ToString(item.value)));
}
comboBox1.ValueMember = "value";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
```

MaterialRepository.cs

```
public List<dynamic> GetList(int idQuery)
{
    using (DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection()) //Open a MySQLConnection
    {
         const string query = @"SELECT code,value FROM table1 WHERE id = @Id";
         var par = new {Id = idQuery};

         return db.con.Query<dynamic>(query, par).ToList();
    }
}
```

ComboBoxItem.cs

```
 public class ComboBoxItem
{
    public string name;
    public string value;

    public ComboBoxItem(string name,string value)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: Why use `dynamic` instead of a custom class if that is giving you issues?

Comment: It's part of the question, I would like to know if there's a way to bind the list directly to the combobox without using a custom class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dynamic` has this tendency of making everything that touches it `dynamic` as well, which pretty much nullifies type safety and all its benefits: you want to cage that monster as early as possible, and avoid leaking it everywhere.

A `MaterialRepository` should expose an `IReadOnlyList<Material>`, not a `List<dynamic>`. First an `IReadOnlyList<T>` because you don't want the client code to have the right to treat the query results as a *list* (think `Add`/`Remove`), but merely as something they can iterate over: an `IEnumerable<T>` would work fine, but an `IReadOnlyList<T>` is better because then the client code won't trigger any warnings when it tries to iterate it more than once - which is something you have no control over from the repository class. And since you're already doing `.ToList()`, might as well expose it as such to your clients.

What you're missing is a proper abstraction for your materials; what if you eventually need more than just `Code` and `Value`? With a `Material` class, you could do this:

```
return db.con
         .Query<dynamic>(query, par)
         .Select(item => new Material
             {
                 Code = item.Code.ToString(), 
                 Value = item.Value.ToString()
             })
         .ToList();
```

And then you no longer need that `ComboBoxItem` class - instead you can have `Material` instances in your combo box! ..and if you have more than just a `Code` and a `Value` to display, you can get all that information at once, and reuse it.

Also you should consider using a `BindingList` to data-bind your items instead of manually adding them:

```
var materialsBindingList = new BindingList(materials);
comboBox1.DataSource = materialsBindingList;
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Code";
```

That would pave the way to more modern UI frameworks, like Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), where data binding is your go-to way of feeding data into a UI.

---

Name things. `comboBox1` needs a name. It contains a material that the user selected. `SelectedMaterial` seems like a much more meaningful name for it.

In this snippet:

> ```
> var mRep= new MaterialRepository();
>
> comboBox1.Items.Clear();
> foreach (var item in listMaterial)
> ```

It's not clear where `listMaterial` is coming from, and the coupling between what appears to be your UI (/form) and that `MaterialRepository` class isn't ideal either. Why instantiate a new `MaterialRepository` every time you need to call into it?

WinForms works well with a *Model-View-Presenter* pattern; you make a class to hold your "model" (exposing the available materials, user selections, etc.), and then the "view" uses it to get its data and store the state of things; the "presenter" coordinates everything, populates the "model", feeds it to the "view" and knows how and when to display and tear down the UI.

Refactoring toward MVP would help decouple your components and help with separating the application logic from the data access and UI components.

Comment: I have indeed a Material class but it takes more time to get a list of Material object. My primary objective here is populate the combo in the fastest way possibile.

Comment: I didn't know you could create a class object without all the fields! I indeed have a Material class and you're method works like a charm. I  tried returning a List of Material objects before but it was taking a long time since I was creating the full object with fields I didn't need. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @SilentRage47 it works because the type is mutable and there's a default constructor ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I didn't use Drapper, but I believe that your problem is caused by trying to put dynamic type objects into a combo box. AFAIK `ComboBox` uses a reflection mechanism to get `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`. I see that running a reflection for dynamic type can be a [little problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634858/how-do-i-reflect-over-the-members-of-dynamic-object).

Your idea with switching a type to put it into the `ComboBox` is the proper way to go, but You can do it even easier with using an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). This way the file `ComboBoxItem.cs` will not be necessary, and the reflection inside `ComboBox` guts will work properly.

```
var mRep = new MaterialRepository();

comboBox1.Items.Clear();
foreach (var item in listMaterial)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(new { name = Convert.ToString(item.code), value = Convert.ToString(item.value) });
}
comboBox1.ValueMember = "value";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
```

I strongly suggest switching from WinForms to WPF and MVVM pattern.